# Showing 1 of 2 components on button click

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, if-statement, onclick

On the parent component, I am trying to do 2 buttons, each of them will show a component, the first button shows itemlist and second component shows itemlist2 but I couldn't seem to get it right, I tried to follow this example (https://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/yaVaLK) even though I'm not sure its the right resource for such feature, here is my app.js code

```
  class App extends Component {
  state = {
    one: false
  };

  handleClick(e) {
    const userChoice = e.target.className;
    this.setState({
      userChoice
    });
  }

  toggleDiv() {
    this.setState({
      one: !this.state.one
    });
  }

  toggleDiv1() {
    this.setState({
      one: this.state.one
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <ServiceSelector toggleDiv={this.toggleDiv.bind(this)} toggleDiv1= 
          {this.toggleDiv1.bind(this)} />
          {this.state.one == false ? <ItemList /> : <ItemList2 />}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ServiceSelector extends React.Component {
  toggleDiv() {
    this.props.toggleDiv();
  }
  toggleDiv2() {
    this.props.toggleDiv2();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {" "}
        <button onClick={this.toggleDiv.bind(this)}>sss </button>
        <button onClick={this.toggleDiv1.bind(this)}>sss </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where is the call for ServiceSelector class in your App class??
Also, I see that you have a binding for toggleDiv1 in ServiceSelector but there aren't any method defined as toggleDiv1

Comment: @wnl check the new edits, ive already added it, and i tried changing button's toggleDiv to onClick, console(TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined)

Comment: right now, you only passing toggleDiv() as props to ServiceSelector, you have to pass both  toggleDiv() and toggleDiv1().

Comment: I added this also just now  <ServiceSelector
            toggleDiv={this.toggleDiv.bind(this)}
            toggleDiv1={this.toggleDiv1.bind(this)}
          />
still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not too sure about what you trying to do but i am gonna give it a try.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    one: false
  };

  handleClick(e) {
    const userChoice = e.target.className;
    this.setState({
      userChoice
    });
  }

  toggleDiv = () => {
    this.setState({
      one: !this.state.one
    });
  }

  toggleDiv1 = () => {
    this.setState({
      one: this.state.one
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <ServiceSelector toggleDiv={this.toggleDiv} toggleDiv1={this.toggleDiv1} />
          {this.state.one == false ? <ItemList /> : <ItemList2 />}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ServiceSelector extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {" "}
        <button onClick={this.props.toggleDiv}>sss </button>
        <button onClick={this.props.toggleDiv1}>sss </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Using arrow functions remove the need of typing this.bind as it does the binding for you

Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this function

```
toggleDiv1() {
  this.setState({
    one: this.state.one
  });
}
```

is useless.

The toggle function should have one

```
toggleFunc() {
  this.setState({stateWatched = !this.state.stateWatched})
}
```

Use this function in both case(set `true` or `false`). And don't `bind` when call in `ServiceSelector` component, this is nonesense.

```js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    one: false
  };

  handleClick(e) {
    const userChoice = e.target.className;
    this.setState({
      userChoice
    });
  }

  toggleDiv() {
    this.setState({
      one: !this.state.one
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <ServiceSelector toggleDiv={this.toggleDiv.bind(this)} />
          {this.state.one == false ? <ItemList /> : <ItemList2 />}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ServiceSelector extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {" "}
        <button onClick={this.props.toggleDiv}>sss </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to have 2 buttons to handle toggle. Change the logic of the function.

```
function toggleTrue() {
  this.setState({one: true})
}

function toggleFalse() {
  this.setState({one: false})
}
```

and then pass it like normal (remember to remove `bind` function in a child component )